# How to add directories in unite.vim plugin?

Tags: vim, editor, unite.vim

In my `.vimrc` file I set the following mapping key:

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-p> :<C-u>Unite -buffer-name=files -start-insert buffer file_mru file_rec:!<CR>
```

When I hit `C-p`, it shows me files in the directory and history. How can I tell vim to show me some special directories content?

I mean adding directories as default source files place.

Comment: How about using set path command?